# How to export specific folders from Exchange Mailbox' online archive to PST

Tags: exchange, powershell

I am trying to export specific folders (and their subfolders) to PST files from an online archive of a mailbox. Servers are running Exchange 2010 (14.3.123.4) on Server 2008 R2.

So far I have this:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest `
    -Mailbox $Mailbox `
    -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#/Production/Bouwnummers/$BouwnummerFolder/*" `
    -FilePath "\\[server]\PST-Export$\OTPM\$BouwnummerFolder.pst" `
    -Name $Bouwnummer `
    -DomainController $DomainController

New-MailboxExportRequest `
    -Mailbox $Mailbox `
    -IncludeFolders "#Inbox#/Production/Bouwnummers/$BouwnummerFolder/*" `
    -FilePath "\\[server]\PST-Export$\OTPM\$BouwnummerFolder Archive.pst" `
    -Name "$Bouwnummer Archive"`
    -DomainController $DomainController `
    -IsArchive
```

For the first export request, I get the expected result, however for the archive (2nd part) I only get the Deleted items folder (empty). I have checked with `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $Mailbox -Archive | ft Folderpath | out-file E:\PST-Export\$Mailbox-archive.txt` that it does contain the folder, and subfolders that I want.

So, how can I export the folders from the online archive to PST?

Comment: In your second example, what happens if you don't have a -IncludeFolders? Is the -isArchive parameter setting it to use all archived folders, therefore you don't need to explicitly state a folder?

Comment: I will try that as soon as I get at work, but I expect to get the whole archive into PST then (350 GB of it). So I do only want to export a specific folder within the archive.

Comment: So, without -IncludeFolders it did export the full archive. But I've found the solution, which I will post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution was that -IncludeFolders parameter did not accept #inbox# to make it language agnostic (as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299(v=exchg.160).aspx#Parameters)) **when -InArchive was also given**. So I had to use -IncludeFolders parameter without the #-signs to retrieve specific folders from the online archive.